# Mapping Keyboard and Mouse movement to background web page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, autoit

I am doing my Google Summer of Code project. In this project I am capturing the screen using Google Chrome's Screen Capture extension and then displaying it on my webpage.

Now I want to interact with the Screens Captured by this extension. Is there something I can do to map keyboard and mouse movement to the original web page that I'm capturing?

Perhaps the JavaScript way or use of other scripting languages like AutoIT?

This is exactly what I want to do: [Demo Video](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1WarJ94rfQcZlBrSE5KS2l0dWM/edit?usp=drive_web)

Comment: Define "mapping", if you want the hidden (iframe? display none?) page to get the events, you can use direct JS calls if both pages on same domain or postMessage if different domains

Answer (score 0):

I think that you mean you want to send mouse and keyboard clicks to a hidden window using AutoIt?

- to send keyboard typing, use [`ControlSend`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlSend.htm)
- to send mouse clicks, use [`ControlClick`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm)

You must get the control ID of the window first.